# How to set custom page as default page for customer account?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, magento

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I just logged in as customer in my site default its showing 'DashBoard' i want set it as custom page (order history) is it possible or not ? If yes How ?

How can i do this one in Magento CE1.7

may be its a duplicate question Sorry just forgive me..

Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't know magento, but you can redirect in your custom page after the user is logged in... in php you can use: header(Location), or you can use htaccess rules, or so on...

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help

```
<?php Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl("sales/order/history/"));?>
```

Or try this extension :
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-login-redirect.html

Comment: Thanks @Marwen   in which location i haf to place this code ?

Comment: already i tried that extension if i use this extension i'm getting some problem in Seller account

Comment: for normal customers i have to get this & for seller i have to get default one only if i used this extension means its checking the url for both my requirements for only normal customers....

Comment: hi @Jhon , you can place this code in customer/form/login.phtml

Comment: Go to app/design/frontend/Your_Package/Your_Theme/template/customer/form/login.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. Rewrite `Mage_Customer_AccountController`   and override `_loginPostRedirect()`
2. Change the submit action of the form to your custom controller
3. Use Observer on post dispatch action  and do the redirect in your Observer method.

As you are new no magento the first solution is going to be a bit easier.

Good luck!

Comment: @Marwen Jelloul has a fine solution for this! Forget about my solution!

Comment: Thanks @mischa Leiss I'm new for this Can you please explain more about this ?